# Is there any automated way to pull Elastic Search Data to Google Project

Tags: elasticsearch, google-cloud-platform, etl

I've been looking everywhere, however all code I can find is focusing on pushing data from GCP into Elastic Search. For example this one https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/export-google-cloud-data-into-elasticsearch-with-dataflow-templates

I'm looking for a way to do the opposite. Push data from Elastic to GCP.

What is the easiest way? Is it even possible with Google Data Flow?